Multi-Org Testnet fails in synchronizing. (Using EOS notechain boilerplate)
I am able to setup Multi-Org (4 organization) EOS network using docker. However I am not able to get the details executed by org1 action to the other nodes (i.e org2, org3 and org4). I get the account info in all orgs but not table details.
The dockerfile to fetch EOS binaries is as follows:
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget sudo curl
RUN wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases/download/v1.8.1/eosio.cdt_1.8.1-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt install -y ./eosio.cdt_1.8.1-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
RUN wget https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/download/v2.0.13/eosio_2.0.13-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt install -y ./eosio_2.0.13-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb

The overview of my setup is as follows:
I am running 4 distributed nodes in Docker containers, each docker container representing a different organization in a supply chain network on the EOS blockchain. The setup includes:
Nodes and Ports:

Org1: Port 8888
Org2: Port 8889
Org3: Port 8890
Org4: Port 8891

The containers are connected via an external Docker network (notechain_network).
A sample docker-compose yaml file for org2 is as follows:
version: '2.0'
services:
  eosio_base:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my_eosio_image:latest
    networks:
      - notechain_network  # Use existing network

  org2_eosio_notechain_container:
    image: my_eosio_image:latest
    depends_on:
      - eosio_base
    ports:
      - "8889:8889"
      - "9877:9877"
    environment:
      - ORG=org2
      - EOSIO_DATA_DIR=/mnt/dev/org2/data
      - EOSIO_HTTP_SERVER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8889
      - EOSIO_P2P_LISTEN_ENDPOINT=0.0.0.0:9877
    volumes:
      - ./org2/contracts:/opt/eosio/bin/org2/contracts
      - ./org2/data:/mnt/dev/org2/data
      - ./org2/scripts:/opt/eosio/bin/scripts
    command: /bin/bash -c "./opt/eosio/bin/scripts/init_blockchain.sh"
    networks:
      - notechain_network  # Use existing network

And in the init_blockchain.sh script for org2, I run the nodeos instance and also create account. Also configured --p2p-peer-address in nodeos instance, which seems to be the basis for connecting to other peer nodes. Here is the sample code:(Note I am using the same scope and account for all the orgs)
set -m
# Start nodeos (local node of blockchain) with organization-specific configurations
nodeos -e -p eosio \
  --data-dir="${EOSIO_DATA_DIR}" \
  --config-dir /mnt/dev/config \
  --http-validate-host=false \
  --plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
  --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
  --plugin eosio::http_plugin \
  --http-server-address="${EOSIO_HTTP_SERVER_ADDRESS}" \
  --p2p-listen-endpoint="${EOSIO_P2P_LISTEN_ENDPOINT}" \
  --p2p-peer-address=org1_eosio_notechain_container:9876 \
  --p2p-peer-address=org3_eosio_notechain_container:9878 \
  --p2p-peer-address=org4_eosio_notechain_container:9879 \
  --access-control-allow-origin=* \
  --contracts-console \
  --verbose-http-errors &

# Wait for nodeos to be ready
sleep 1s

echo "Nodes running at : http://${EOSIO_HTTP_SERVER_ADDRESS}/v1/chain/get_info "
until curl -s "http://${EOSIO_HTTP_SERVER_ADDRESS}/v1/chain/get_info"
do
  echo "Waiting for nodeos to start..."
  sleep 1s
done

echo "=== nodeos for ${ORG} is up and running ==="

# Set up wallets, accounts, and deploy smart contracts
# Adjust wallet and account names to include ORG to prevent conflicts

echo "=== Setting up wallet: ${ORG}_eosiomain ==="
cleos wallet create -n eosiomain --to-console | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' > eosiomain_wallet_password.txt
cleos wallet import -n eosiomain --private-key 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkXXX

echo "=== Setting up wallet: ${ORG}_notechainwal ==="
cleos wallet create -n notechainwal --to-console | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' > notechain_wallet_password.txt
cleos wallet import -n notechainwal --private-key 5JpWT4ehouB2FF9aCfdfnZ5AwbQbTtHBAwebRXt94FmjyXXXXX
cleos wallet import -n notechainwal --private-key 5JD9AGTuTeD5BXZwGQ5AtwBqHK21aHmYnTetHgk1B3pjjXXXXX

# create account for notechainacc with above wallet's public keys
cleos -u http://${EOSIO_HTTP_SERVER_ADDRESS} create account eosio vcontract1 EOS6PUh9rs7eddJNzqgqDx1QrspSHLRxLMcRdwHZZRL4tpbtviXXX EOS8BCgapgYA2L4LJfCzekzeSr3rzgSTUXRXwNi8bNRoz31D14XXX

echo "=== Deploying smart contract for ${ORG} ==="
deploy_contract.sh foodscm vcontract1 notechainwal $(cat notechain_wallet_password.txt)

I am executing action using EOSJS library a sample code is as follows:
export async function createFertilizers(submission, formData, org) {

    console.log("Default Private Key:", currKey)
    const userName = sessionStorage.getItem("current_user");
    const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([currKey]);
    const rpc_url = getIPaddress(org);
    const rpc = new JsonRpc(rpc_url, { nodeFetch });
    const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });

    const result = await api.transact({

        "actions": [
            {
                "account": "vcontract1",
                "name": "crfertsol",
                "authorization": [
                    {
                        "actor": userName,
                        "permission": "active"
                    }
                ],
                "data": {
                    "username": userName,
                    "fdata": submission,
                    "formdataf": formData
                },
            }]
    },
        {
            "blocksBehind": 3,
            "expireSeconds": 30,
        }).then(notifySuccess('Uploading'));
    console.log("Uploading Result: ", result)
    return result

The data is seen in table in org1 using port 8888. However the data is not seen in other ports or orgs (i.e 8889, 8890 and 8891).
root@2c22a0421fc6:/# cleos -u http://127.0.0.1:8889 get table vcontract1 vcontract1 fertdytbl
{
  "rows": [],
  "more": false,
  "next_key": ""
}

Can anyone guide me what am I missing or doing wrong. I am not able to figure out the setup. Any help would be much appreciated.
